# How can I find count of comments per user per hour in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

Table1

```
post_id  | num_comments
3421     | 1
6472     | 3
7294     | 0
4891     | 4
```

Table2

```
post_id  | user_id | timestamp
3421     | 100     | 2022-03-30 06:47:30.000000000
6472     | 100     | 2022-03-30 06:48:00.000000000
6472     | 101     | 2022-03-30 06:52:30.000000000
6472     | 101     | 2022-03-30 06:53:30.000000000
4891     | 102     | 2022-03-30 06:57:30.000000000
4891     | 102     | 2022-03-30 06:59:30.000000000
4891     | 103     | 2022-03-30 06:59:45.000000000
4891     | 104     | 2022-03-30 07:01:00.000000000
```

As you can see, each `post_id` can have multiple `user_id` assigned to it.
I need to find the count of comments per `user_id` per hour.

I have tried the below code but it only gives me the count of comments per post per hour, not per user. I need the count per user per hour.

```
select t1.user_id, date_part(hour, t2.timestamp) as hour, 
    count(t2.num_comments) as comments
from Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 
    on t1.post_id = t2.post_id
group by t1.user_id, t2.timestamp;
```

Comment: `find the count of comments per user_id per hour` Are you actually storing comments by user or just by post id? It's hard to tell with the generic table names.... If "Table2" represents comment records, do a `count(t2.post_id)` and group by the "hour" not `timestamp`.  Also, are you sure you're using MySQL? It doesn't have a date_part() function.

Comment: @SOS I'm storing comments by user_id and post_id. And I'm using Snowflake database so I guess its using SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate by user and hour:

```sql
SELECT t1.user_id, DATE_FORMAT(t2.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AS hour,
       COUNT(t2.num_comments) AS comments
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.post_id = t2.post_id
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Note that if you want to guarantee that every hour between two certain dates will appear in your report, and your data might *not* have every hour present, then you will have to make use of something known as a calendar table, which is a table containing all dates/hours which you want to appear.